# Add a list as a column to dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataFrame with 18 rows of records, and this dataFrame has like 20+ columns.
For example:

```
-----------                My list: ('N','N')
A   B   C
-----------
a   b   c
d   e   f
```

I also have a list with 18 values. Now I want to add this list to my dataFrame, each value in a list correspond a value to the row.

That means the final result should be like this:

```
--------------
A   B   C   D
--------------
a   b   c   N
d   e   f   N
```

Here is what I tried(From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395873/apache-spark-how-to-append-new-column-from-list-array-to-spark-dataframe)):

```
//C is a list of values
val rdd = sc.parallelize(C)

//joindf is my dataframe has 20+ columns
val rdd_new = joindf.rdd.zip(rdd).map(r => Row.fromSeq(r._1.toSeq ++ Seq(r._2)))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_new,joindf.schema.add("CD",StringType)).show
```

This gives me error like this:`Can't zip RDDs with unequal numbers of partitions: List(200,2)`

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Not sure why the partition or the zip doesn't work out, but the comments provide another way to do this. I just duplicate the method from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382052/how-to-convert-listdouble-to-columns)

Comment: I think you should take a look at `typedLit`. Available with Spark 2.1+ , I guess.

Comment: It's available with 2.2+ I am using 1.6

Comment: Have you tried to set the partitions to be the same? `val rdd = sc.parallelize(C, joindf.rdd.partitions.size)`?

Comment: @Psidom I just tried, and it's giving me a wave of errors, saying can only zip RDDs with same number of elements. But I checked! They both have a count of 18... Is it because my joindf has over 20 columns and C is just a list with 18 elements?

Comment: The first check should be whether the data frame has 18 rows as well. And then you might to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687149/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-partition) to see if each partition contain same number of elements.

Comment: @Psidom Just checked, joindf.count is 18, also tried the methods in the link, I did a collect on both rdd and they are the same if I am not blind

Comment: Take a look at @vdep's link, which is a more general answer, when the partitions of the data frame and rdd are not the same.

Comment: @vdep Thank you it worked...

Comment: @Psidom it worked, thank god. I do have a question tho, is it okay to use this method for large datasets?

Comment: I think that's the only method you can add a column from a rdd at the moment, so you'll have to try it out. Consider [repartition](https://hackernoon.com/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4) your data frame and rdd though.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at that.