# How to convert array of type double[] to spark column?

Tags: java, apache-spark

How to create a dataframe with two columns, namely `p_vals` and `t_vals`, containing values obtained from `GeneralizedLinearRegression`, that is `summary.tValues()` and `summary.pValues()`. Both of those values are of double[] type. My question is how can I convert `summary.tValues()` and `summary.pValues()` to column types so the dataframe can be created. I am trying to do this in Java.

I have tried the following, which didn't work due to the argument type mismatch.

```
df = df.withColumn("T Values", summary.tValues())
   .withColumn("P Values", summary.pValues());
```

Comment: did you tried lit function like this lit(summary.pValues()) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert List\[Double\] to Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382052/how-to-convert-listdouble-to-columns)